# Array pop blows up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array I've created inside an object of my global variables:

```
var g = {       
    misc1     : null,
    misc2     : null,
    thumbStack  : []
}
```

I use this as a stack with push and pop. The page visitor is able to delete thumbnail images on the page but the thumbnails don't really get deleted at that time; they just go on the thumbStack and get deleted on exit (at least that's the plan). So the delete might do something like:

```
g.thumbStack.push(thumb4);
```

Then I catch the page exit with:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
    var thumb;
    while(g.thumbStack.length) {
         thumb = g.thumbStack(pop);

                     -- do the delete --
        }
});
```

The problem is that when I try to step through the exit code with Firebug, it blows up and jumps into jQuery.min when I execute the line that pops a value off of thumbStack.

Does anyone see the problem here?
Thanks

Comment: An Array is not callable. `g.thumbStack(pop);`

Comment: @Dan455 I think he is trying to `g.thumbStack.pop()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
g.thumbStack(pop)
```

It should be:

```
g.thumbStack.pop()
```